# nodejs get promise object value

Tags: node.js

I want to verify a jwt, and I get this back:

```
Promise {
  {
    id: 'eec46cd4-dfb8-4495-8a25-10b6232e4b3c',
    iat: 1619072483,
    exp: 1625120483
  }
}
```

How can I only get the ID ?
.............
...........
Code

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const util = require('util');

const jwtVerifyAsync = util.promisify(jwt.verify);

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.body.body;
  
  try {
    const verify = jwtVerifyAsync(token, 'SECRET-TOKEN');
    console.log(verify)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
};
```

Comment: From where are you getting this Promise ? Can you add that code?

Comment: from verify. look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `await` and then check the value:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const util = require('util');

const jwtVerifyAsync = util.promisify(jwt.verify);

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.body.body;
  
  try {
    const verify = await jwtVerifyAsync(token, 'SECRET-TOKEN'); // add await as it will return the promise
    console.log(verify)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
};
```